# Memory management of Swift closures passed to C functions

Tags: c, swift

A common idiom in C for callback functions is:

```
void set_callback(
    /* the object using the callback */
    void *obj,
    /* a pointer to user data */
    void *context,
    /* the callback function, first parameter is context above */
    int (*callback_func)(void *context, obj *a, obj *b),
    /*  an optional destructor function for cleaning up context */
    void (*destructor_function)(void *)
);
```

`destructor_function` is called when `obj` is destroyed to clean up any memory associated with `context`.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to utilize this code structure in Swift.  Specifically, I'm writing an SQLite wrapper and I'd like to be able to add new collation sequences with an API like:

```
typealias StringComparator = (String, String) -> ComparisonResult
func add(collation name: String, _ block: @escaping StringComparator)
```

In Obj-C I would `Block_copy(block)` as `context`, use the copied block in the callback itself, and `Block_release(context)` in the destructor function.

Thus far I haven't found a solution I like equally well in Swift, but I have come up with two working alternatives.  I've omitted most error handling in the code for brevity.

**Option One**

```
// Assume `db` is an `sqlite3 *` object from somewhere
func add(collation name: String, _ block: @escaping StringComparator) {
    let storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<StringComparator>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    storage.initialize(to: block)
    sqlite3_create_collation_v2(db, name, SQLITE_UTF8, storage, { (context, lhs_len, lhs_data, rhs_len, rhs_data) -> Int32 in
        guard let lhs = String(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: lhs_data.unsafelyUnwrapped), length: Int(lhs_len), encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false) else { return 0 }
        guard let rhs = String(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: rhs_data.unsafelyUnwrapped), length: Int(rhs_len), encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false) else { return 0 }
        let storage = context.unsafelyUnwrapped.assumingMemoryBound(to: StringComparator.self)
        return Int32(storage.pointee(lhs, rhs).rawValue)
    }, { context in
        let storage = context.unsafelyUnwrapped.assumingMemoryBound(to: StringComparator.self)
        storage.deinitialize()
        storage.deallocate(capacity: 1)
    })
}
```

While this works in my limited testing, I am not sure whether `block` is actually copied when assigned to `storage`.  I have a feeling this is a fragile solution.

**Option Two**

```
class CollationSequence {
    var comparator: StringComparator
    init(_ comparator: @escaping StringComparator) {
        self.comparator = comparator
    }
}

func add(collation name: String, _ block: @escaping StringComparator) {
    let collationSequence = CollationSequence(block)
    let storage = Unmanaged.passRetained(collationSequence)
    sqlite3_create_collation_v2(db, name, SQLITE_UTF8, storage.toOpaque(), { (context, lhs_len, lhs_data, rhs_len, rhs_data) -> Int32 in
        guard let lhs = String(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: lhs_data.unsafelyUnwrapped), length: Int(lhs_len), encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false) else { return 0 }
        guard let rhs = String(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: rhs_data.unsafelyUnwrapped), length: Int(rhs_len), encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false) else { return 0 }
        let collationSequence = Unmanaged<CollationSequence>.fromOpaque(context.unsafelyUnwrapped).takeUnretainedValue()
        return Int32(collationSequence.comparator(lhs, rhs).rawValue)
    }, { context in
        _ = Unmanaged<CollationSequence>.fromOpaque(context.unsafelyUnwrapped).takeRetainedValue()
    })
}
```

I feel more confident about the memory management in this solution, but I dislike it because of the introduction of a class that doesn't serve as much more than a coat hanger.

Which of these solutions is preferable?  Is there a more elegant solution I've missed?

Comment: By C did you mean Objective-C?  Please check both the title and the tags.

Comment: @CortAmmon No, a straight C API (`sqlite3.h`) called from Swift.

Comment: I am more familiar with option 2, but option 1 *should* work as well. Closures are value types and `storage.initialize(to: block)` stores a reference to the block in the allocated memory. However, that should be balanced by a `storage.deinitialize()` to release the reference.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the *pointer* about `deinitialize()`.  I've edited the code to reflect your correction.

Comment: I do not have the setup to test it, but `let storage = Unmanaged.passRetained(block as AnyObject)` would be another option, using that anything can be "auto boxed" to AnyObject in Swift 3. That's would be #2 without a custom class. – The "unboxing" would be `let block = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(context).takeUnretainedValue() as! StringComparator`.

Comment: I meant: "Closures are *reference* types" ...

Comment: I'm not sure about option one, because the closure is not retained. SQLite may well call the correct code, assuming the closure code is statically stored somewhere. But this code may refer to deallocated data (I'm talking about the variable captured by the closure). So it may work until the collation captures some context (which should not happen very often). You should experiment. The second solution is guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: @GwendalRoué: Unless I am mistaken, `storage.initialize(to: block)` retains the block. A reference to the block is stored in the pointed-to memory.

Comment: All right Martin, that's good to know. We're all still a little bit confused :-)

Comment: I wrote a quick playground to test things out and @MartinR seems to be correct about the behavior of `initialize(to:)`.  https://gist.github.com/sbooth/ee86d52e03a5cfa42d725dbcb183a465